# Displaying a SQL table data for a specific user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to display the table `participantes` with the columns `sorteo`, `nombre` and `fecha`.

The user info is on another table `sellify_users` (`usern` column).

I want to display only that user data using:

```
SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE nombre = 'usern'
```

But `usern` is not in the same table, so if possible I want to call the `sellify_users` to get the `usern` data.

```
<?php 
   $user = 'database_user'; 
   $password = 'database_pass'; 
   $database="database_name"; 
   mysql_connect(localhost,$user, $password);  
   @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
   echo $query = "SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE nombre='usern'";      
   $result = mysql_query($query); 
   mysql_close(); 
   ?>
```

Comment: 1) Use proper text/code format 2) Avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql functions

Comment: Is this both a MySQL and MS SQL Server question? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant that a user has a record in the table `sellify_users` and you need to find the `usern` from it in order to use it in the next query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE nombre='usern'";
```

Then all you need to do is to run a query for the table `sellify_users` first and get the value `usern` from it, store it in a variable and then use that in your second query. Something like:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM sellify_users";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$usern = $row1['usern'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE nombre='usern'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
echo $row2['ColumnNameHere1'];
echo $row2['ColumnNameHere2'];
}
```

> Notice: I've passed `$con` which denotes a connection variable, i.e.
>   you should read about mysqli or PDO and if there's anything you do not understand, feel free to shoot a query.

**EDIT:**

*If by any chance* you are trying to use the last inserted record, you should look for `mysqli_insert_id($con);` and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is a screenshot of what i want to display in a bootstrap table:
http://prntscr.com/8k37dy
So i want to filter that results by the usern located in table(sellify_users) and the info of (nombre,sorteo and fecha) is located on table(participantes)

Comment: @AlvaroSanchez Was my answer of any help? If not, please explain what exactly you want? and other than that the screenshot you posted has a syntactical error near the line `$row[nobmre];`, which should be quote as `$row['nobmre'];`

Comment: I cant get it work man, sorry but im not an advanced user in this language...
Here is the code       http://pastebin.com/JdUaY3ws

Comment: @AlvaroSanchez relax man, I have fixed some of the code where you were mixing the `mysql_*` API's with `mysqli` along with enabling `error_reporting` here: http://pastebin.com/cYGC4p0L Now what errors/unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: Thanks you for the replies man, i dont know what im doing worng.. I want to display on a html table the users details (nombre,sorteo and fecha) located on sql table (participantes) and display the user details filtering by the usern located on sellify_users.
Man, i have a code that shows the user username and if i can put on 
"SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE nombre='CODEHERE'";
It dont be necesary all of this, the code is:
<?php echo (idinfo($_SESSION['ps_usern'],"usern")); ?> but i dont know how to put on WHERE nombre='CODEHERE'";

Comment: @AlvaroSanchez Np, but that's way too confusing. 1) I don't know how your table structure looks like. 2) What is `idinfo();`? 3) If the value is stored in a session _correctly_ and you can even _echo_ it and its easy to pass it on the `WHERE` clause bu simply saving it in another variable i.e. `$var = $_SESSION['ps_usern'];` and then `WHERE nombre='$var';`

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEES!!! finally i get it works! thanks man you helped me alot! its works with $var really thanks man you are awesome :)
Edit: one last thing, when i start the page i see: SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE nombre='Seguro19' 
How i can hide this?

Comment: @AlvaroSanchez Ahh, I'm glad you made it ^_^ Go and do something more amazing now! cheers

Comment: @AlvaroSanchez Use `isset` in a way like `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // your code here }` Where you must have an input field with name attribute in your HTML like `<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Save"/>`